# Remove the moderator tags from the tag-list for non-moderators

Tags: feature-request

The moderator tags appear in the tag selection list when creating or editing a post. Example with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured):

[image]

As a non moderator it appears, can be selected but can't be used:

[image: An error message appears below the tags stating the 'featured' tag can only be used by moderators.]

Why show them when the can't even be used? This doesn't really make sense for me and they should be removed.

This would also remove the need for validation that the are used in the first place.

Comment: _“This would also remove the need for validation that the are used in the first place.”_ — but the validation for tag creation would still need to be in place, though it would likely be more confusing, since a tag couldn’t be created that doesn’t appear on the suggestion list. This is likely too complex for too little of a benefit.

Comment: What's gained by removing these from the suggestion list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Displaying the tag lets users know that the tag exists, so we won't get constant questions asking what the mysterious [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is and why it isn't showing up for them. The tag wiki summary already tells you that it's moderator-only, so there is no need for you to try adding it to your question.

Comment: Valid point and from a direction I've not looked at.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it would be unneccesary. It's just shown as a tag, it has to be shown as it exists and (2) questions are under it and it even says moderator-only before anything. It isn't hard to just remove the tag from a question if you select it. It would be unnecessary to change the tag so that it isn't shown to non-moderators, and possibly risky (in the way that it could cause problems just to hide from users) and difficult.